# Which Drupal Modules do I need for a news site?

Tags: drupal

What are some important modules I should install in Drupal if I am going to use it for a news website.

Comment: That is way too general of a question.  I could just start listing a bunch of rad modules, but I don't think that is really productive.  Tell us what features you want your site to have, and we can go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Picxelplay is right, but that said, you may want to check out [Open Publish](http://openpublishapp.com/), a Drupal distribution aimed at newspapers and the like.

Answer (score 1):

For a news site you're probably, at the very least, wanting:

**CCK**- gives you the ability to create custom nodes

**pathauto**- allows the automatic creation of human readable urls

**views**- very versatile module that lets you create aggregates of content based on rules and restriction

**Panels**- lets you group different pieces of drupal structures on one page (a view, a node and a search form on the same page)

I think the first step is to get your roles set up properly as to who's allowed to do what etc.  And, yes, more information would be much more helpful.

Comment: Don't forget Token which is needed for pathauto.